# Implicity generic struct dosn't work in method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, implicit-conversion, implicit

1 => I use generic strut for return type method , follow code:

```
  public Test<User> Get()
  {

   Test<User> user = new Test<User>();
   return user;

  }
```

Use method:

```
Test<User> retUser = Get();//Implicity error can not convert User to User
```

2=>But in other hand :

```
  Test<User> user = new Test<User>();
  Test<User> user2 = user;//No error implicity Why??
```

What's difference between 1,2 Codes ?

Comment: Could you please provide exact error message instead of coming up with your own version?

Comment: What is the full namespace for both `User`'s? Also, I wouldn't recommend just creating a method called `Get` it seems very uninformative

Comment: I guess you have couple of `User` classes. Post the full and actual error message

Comment: Sounds more like an ambiguous `User` namespace issue.

Comment: name space is correct can't implicity TestApp.User to TestApp.User

Comment: You should add the complete error message to your question

Comment: Visual studio debugger has been confused , I fix other error in other ClassLibrary that does not care my code .

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have 2 `User` classes, use the refactoring tools to rename one and you'll probably end up with either this

```
Test<Foo> retUser = Get();//Implicity error can not convert User to Foo
```

or this

```
Test<User> retUser = Get();//Implicity error can not convert Foo to User
```

You'll then need to delete/merge the 2 classes to remove the ambiguituy

Comment: No I have a User class

Comment: Visual studio debugger has been confused , I fix other error in other ClassLibrary that does not care my code .